# How non-blocking mysql client actually works?

Tags: mysql, node.js, nonblocking

I recently saw a piece of node.js code like below, which is supposed to run as a standalone service, without restarting every time when new requests are received:

```
switch(action) {
    case 'a':
        connectMysql(function(mysqlConnection) {
            // some queries X
        });
        break;
    case 'b':
        connectMysql(function(mysqlConnection) {
            // some queries Y
        });
        break;
    /***** more actions *****/
}
```

It opens a new MySQL connection each time for each action, and the one who wrote this believes that this approach could make sure queries are executed in parallel and won't block each other when there're a huge request amount in the same time.

This really confused me, because I thought the mysql client for node.js is  non-blocking, which won't block anything.

If any chances the queries were stuck, the reason might be the process was handling too many requests, and more mysql connections definitely won't help.

Or, a non-blocking client just mean that it will send queries asynchronously, but the queries will eventually be blocked in the mysql server-side when there're too much queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MySQL protocol does not permit multiplexing of queries mostly because when you connect to the server, you occupy only a single thread and there is only at most one outstanding query per thread at any given time. So MySQL modules for node typically will implement some sort of queue as a convenience.

Some of the MySQL modules offer built-in connection pooling which allow you to workaround the one-query-per-connection limit while maintaining an upper bound on the number of connections you have to the server (so as not to overwhelm the server and/or run out of socket file descriptors locally). IMHO ultimately the pooling option is the best solution as far as concurrency goes.

The non-blocking aspect just means you don't stop doing anything else while you wait for a query to finish. This allows you to do other things while waiting for the query, such as responding to other web server requests, firing timers, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, just want to make sure I get these right.
So basically mysql server only execute query sequentially from one connection, some clients will implements a queue or a connection pool to keep up with this multiple queries issue.
And the code I posted did somehow solved this problem, but creating a connection pool would be a better option instead of open unlimited connections, right?